# Question I can no longer respond to

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37972/diagnose-brightness-control) about diagnosing why the brightness control won't work. But now the laptop doesn't work any more (water ruined it), so is it possible to name it under someone who is interested in it or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions aren't transferable. As it's something that no longer affects you, and these things are quite make/model-specific I'm going to close it and refund the bounty.

If somebody else has this issue and wants to resurrect the topic, they can ask a similar question and if somebody pokes a moderator, we can merge in the current answers.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks for the support.

Comment: It's not model-specific, I'm only asking how to diagnose it.

Comment: @Oxwivi I see what you mean but as I said in the closing message, these things are usually extremely model-specific. Step one for any laptop issue would should be: Go to Google, search for `<make> <model> ubuntu <problem>`.

Comment: That qualifies as part of an answer. :P